# Matrix multiplication and addition for multiple inputs

Tags: r, matrix, multiplication, addition

How to calculate y = A x + b where A is matrix, b is vector, and x is a matrix
This is the example when x is a vector, which works

```
A <- matrix(c(seq(1,6)),ncol=2,byrow = TRUE)
b <- matrix(c(seq(.5,.7,.1)),ncol=1)
x <- matrix(c(seq(0.1,0.2,0.1)),ncol=1)
y <- A %*% x + b
```

But, what to do when x contains numerous cases, in matrix format.  This works for the A matrix.

```
set.seed(100) 
xt<-matrix(runif(20), ncol=10)
y1 <- A%*%xt
```

But, how to add the constant term to all the columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `apply` function:

```
apply(y1, 2, `+`, b)
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case where the number of columns is the same in each matrix, the R addition function will "recycle" the values of a vector, so it is simply:

```
 y1 + as.vector(b)
```

I will admit that I expected the 'b'-matrix to have it's values recycled by "+" but that an error was thrown about incommensurate dimensions.